# Angular search/filter raw html or ignore word

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code

```
<div class="search-wrapper card">
    <p><input type="text" ng-model="test.some_id"></p>
</div>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in $ctrl.x.data | filter : test">
        <a href="#!/x/{{ x['some_id'] }}" class="thumb">
            SomeWordHere {{ x['some_id'] }}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Currently, the filter will only work for id, if you start typing 'SomeWordHere', it will hide all the results. Is there a way to either make the filter ignore 'SomeWordHere' when it is typed, or allow it so search everything within the li element? The 2nd approach would be preferred if possible

Thanks

Comment: It still erases when 'SomeWordHere' starts to be typed. It just then also searches x for not only ['some_id'] but 'this_id' and 'that_id', so it messes up my results a bit. The current solution works for some_id, but I would like it to work for some_id + the raw html text

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's going to be possible without a whole bunch of code. Filters are meant to apply to collections, not the generated output of an ng-repeat.

Comment: Ah.. I hate angular so much! Do you think it would be easier to just give the li a class and do it with jquery?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using jQuery to do DOM manipulation like that because you'll end up fighting Angular which is also doing DOM manipulation. If you end up going that route it'd be best to write it as a directive and stick the jQuery stuff in the link function. You'd probably be better off writing your own custom filter where you can ignore parts of the filter text as desired.

Comment: Yeah I just realized the what the jQuery a.text returns is literally {{ x['some_id'] }}... I guess I will look into custom filters if it is the only way. Thanks @Lex